# Xamarin.Forms crash on iOS when opening app for a second or third time

Tags: ios, xamarin.forms, visual-studio-app-center

I record crashes in the Microsoft App Center and I've recently started to take a closer look after getting comments from iOS users along the lines of .."your app is good, but I wish it wouldn't ask me to login each day...". My behaviour should be that once you have logged in, the user details are saved locally for 60 days... So, clearly a problem.

I have log entries in the App Center for each time the app crash/logout is occurring. The stack trace looks like this :

```
Xamarin Exception Stack:
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
  at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.TabbedRenderer.SetTabBarItem (Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.IVisualElementRenderer renderer) <0x10256ae00 + 0x003a8> in <fe413c358635490ab5f9ce4c1dde0468#5cddb27fd6b55ddaa4d1b8bcae86b615>:0
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore+<>c.<ThrowAsync>b__7_0 (System.Object state) <0x100f688b0 + 0x00053> in <25bf495f7d6b4944aa395b3ab5293479#5cddb27fd6b55ddaa4d1b8bcae86b615>:0
  at Foundation.NSAsyncSynchronizationContextDispatcher.Apply () <0x101fa70e0 + 0x0002b> in <5b08e01cb6df409eb2fea153e6177e5d#5cddb27fd6b55ddaa4d1b8bcae86b615>:0
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) UIKit.UIApplication.UIApplicationMain(int,string[],intptr,intptr)
  at UIKit.UIApplication.Main (System.String[] args, System.String principalClassName, System.String delegateClassName) <0x101fe2950 + 0x0005f> in <5b08e01cb6df409eb2fea153e6177e5d#5cddb27fd6b55ddaa4d1b8bcae86b615>:0
  at MyGrounds.iOS.Application.Main (System.String[] args) <0x100df1850 + 0x00023> in <6fee7fe9093844b8990ac18e5f9a1699#5cddb27fd6b55ddaa4d1b8bcae86b615>:0
```

When a user is logged into my app and it opens up, it should retrieve user info from storage (currently using MonkeyCache with SQLite), then navigate to a 'Profile' tab and populate etc.

Plenty of places where something could go wrong - the exception stack refers specifically to SetTabBarItem though and I'm not sure whether the issue in my code is just being swallowed up somewhere.

This seems to be mainly on iOS as far as I'm aware, but not ruling out that it's also on Android.

It also seems to be occurring after someone has used the app once, then either left it for a period of time, or closed it etc. So this could also be about me not doing some tidying up related to the app lifecycle stages.

What's particularly odd, is after the crash, the next time the user opens the app, they are logged out, so something has happened to the data about them that should have been stored in SQLite. I'm considering switching to Xamarin.Essentials Preferences as I don't store too much data, just as something to try really!

If anyone recognises this error and has any insight, I'd be much appreciated. Also, any suggestions on further routes to debug this would also be super.

Comment: Without knowing anything about your code it’s impossible to say.  I’d first try to replicate it locally.  What conditions would prevent the user from being cached?

Comment: I appreciate it's a big ask 

Comment: Only conditions I don't seem to be catching are if an attempt to store something in the cache fails. I did wonder if during the first use, the user logs in, it fails to cache, so when they next open the app, there is no user info. However,  when the app starts, if there is no user info, it should redirect the user to the login screen (not crash)

Comment: Add try-catch around any code related to the two symptoms: * here: *"then navigate to a 'Profile' tab"*; * Constructor for each tab's page; * where login info is saved (and I assume you already do a sanity check before saving - so you know it isn't being erased); * any custom code in onstart/onresume or onsleep. In the catch, log to a local file. If app starts again successfully, could detect that you saved such a file, and send the information to your server. (clear the file after doing so.)

Comment: Assuming you have a sanity check to make sure you never save bad data (missing username or password), then the data *is not getting corrupted*. Rather, there is some "timing problem". Either you've done some UI operation while not on MainThread (wrap in Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread or similar MainThread method). OR something isn't ready when its needed during the tab switch.

Comment: Thanks for all the advice, I'll digest it and attempt to reproduce locally, I guess if I can't see this happen, it's going to be tricky to know I've fixed it!

Comment: One more thing to establish - would an unhandled exception within my own code result in this sort of exception stack? There is no reference to any code lower than the tab stuff